# ng test = lots of "verify that it is part of this module" errors

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write Jasmine unit tests, but when I run ng test, the terminal goes crazy with errors

example errors

```
 1. If 'mat-radio-group' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'mat-radio-group' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("has-error">
                      <span id="over21Label">Are you over the age of 21?</span>
                      [ERROR ->]<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" name="over21" formControlName="over21">
                     "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/BuyerSignupComponent.html@118:14
        'mat-card' is not a known element:
```

```
 1. If 'mat-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'mat-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-3 mx-auto">
                  [ERROR ->]<mat-card id="signupBox">
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/BuyerSignupComponent.html@14:10unt Registration</div>
```

There's other similar errors too for things like mat-icon, mat-placeholder, etc...

My app.module file is importing these though. When I find similar stackoverflow posts with this kind of error, the answer is to import them in app.module, but they already are.
I'm importing like so

```
import {
  MatInputModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatDividerModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatTooltipModule
} from "@angular/material";
```

and then under imports

```
  ],
  imports: [
MatRadioModule, MatCardModule, etc...
```

So it's being imported so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add it as an import in your testing module (mycomponent.component.spec.ts)

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
     MaterialModule
   ],
   declarations: [MyCmponent],
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```